# Orientation images in <Image>

Tags: react-native

Hi i have problem with image orientation.

```
  test: {
width: 145,
height: 145,  },

<Image
  style={styles.test}
  resizeMode={'cover'}
  source={{ uri: homeSettings ? homeSettings.selfieImageUrl : selfieImageUri   } }
        />
```

Image can be set

```
resizeMode('cover', 'contain', 'stretch')
```

I tried them all.
When I take a picture on portait.
He turns to the mode landscape.  how to set up the picture on the landscape?
Please an example.
Thanks

Comment: Do you get your photos from your Camera roll ? If yes, the orientation is specified. You then can apply a rotation style to display it the way you want.

Comment: No a get patch like    /storage/0/pictures/images.jpg   or  http url